# Retrieve customers with more than one loan

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm struggling to write a SQL query that will identify customers who have taken out multiple loans in a short period of time (say 60 days).

**MyTable**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable](
    [Customerid] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
    [Date Open] [date] NOT NULL,
    [Date Closed] [date] NOT NULL,
    [Rank] [varchar](50) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

E.g. - Customerid 1 has taken multiple loans with date open say 12/01/2017, 12/02/2017, 13/04/2018 etc. I need to find the customers who have taken next loan (Date Open) within 60 days.

Comment: Please provide what you have already tried

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I would recommend reading the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for tips on asking good questions which people will be able and willing to answer for you. Also, the page on [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is very helpful. In this specific instance, it would be useful for you to provide the DDL statement(s) for your table(s), example data and expected output to make your question clear.

Comment: Based on what you have given so far though, it sounds like you should investigate using window functions (specifically [`lead`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can do this with a simple `INNER JOIN`. I'm not entirely sure what `Rank` indicates in your table, but something like below should work if they can't take out two loans on the same day.

```
SELECT DISTINCT yt1.Customerid
FROM yourtable yt1
INNER JOIN yourtable yt2 ON yt2.Customerid = yt1.Customerid AND
                            yt2.[Date Open] > yt1.[Date Open] AND
                            yt2.[Date Open] <= DATEADD(DAY, 60, yt1.[Date Open])
```